# Append a command in a Bash script using a colon and an optional positional parameter?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a small Bash script that runs a command that is essentially one long string containing environment variables, ending in a path to a file.

```
function ios-run-test() {
  thing="DEVICE_TARGET=abcde12345
  DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.1.1:37265
  BUNDLE_ID='com.app.iPhoneEnterprise'
  DISABLE_ADS=1
  env=$1
  DISABLE_LOGIN_INTERSTITIALS=1
  bundle exec cucumber --tags ~@wip --tags ~@ignore --tags ~@android
  ~/Automation/ios-automation/features/$2.feature"

  if [[ $3 ]]; then
    add_this=$3
    thing="${thing:$add_this}"
  fi

  echo ${thing}
  eval universal-variables
  eval ${thing}

}
```

Sometimes that command may end with a `:some_integer`, such as `DEVICE_TARGET=abcde12345 DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.1.1:37265 BUNDLE_ID='com.app.iPhoneEnterprise' DISABLE_ADS=1 env=production DISABLE_LOGIN_INTERSTITIALS=1 bundle exec cucumber --tags ~@wip --tags ~@ignore --tags ~@android ~/Automation/ios-automation/features/login.feature:5`. This is where my problem lies. I have discovered [Substring Extraction](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) which is pretty neat, but is causing this if statement to fail:

```
  if [[ $3 ]]; then
    add_this=$3
    thing="${thing:$add_this}"
  fi
```

Instead of appending `$thing` to have `":$3"` it is removing the first 3 characters of `$thing`. Is there some other way that I'd be able to take an optional positional parameter and append it to the command?

Comment: if you want to append `:$3` to thing just do `thing="${thing}:$3"`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I've missed this. Thank you, Jean-François.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to append `:$3`, then change this line:

> ```
> thing="${thing:$add_this}"
> ```

To this:

```
thing="${thing}:$add_this"
```

Appending values in Bash works by simply writing them one after the other.
The braces are optional in this example,
so simply `thing="$thing:$add_this"` is equivalent.
Inside `${...}` you can perform various advanced operations based on a variable,
but none of that is necessary or relevant for your use case.